# Android-tts voice interrupted

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice

I am new to android developmant.

I am trying to develop an app where on incoming call, the app will speak  " Incoming call from SO and SO".

For this purpose I am using tts.

I am sending a string `Incoming call from NAME`

```
mytts.speak(string, 0, NULL);
```

But the voice generated is interrupted for unknown reasons..

I even tried `TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH` option

But in vain.

I have even turned the ringing volume to zero and infact there is no ringing tone!!
But the voice is still being interrupted!!!!!!!

Comment: What do you mean by interrupted? tts speak only half of the sentence for example

Comment: Is there anything in the logcat. The TTS engine usually logs some stuff to logcat (or at least the TTS engine I've been using). Are there any errors that might pinpoint the problem. It might be worth as well to install a different TTS engine and try that, see if you get the same problem.

Comment: I meant there is lagging in the audio.. Is there any solution to it??

Comment: If the full text is speaking out but lagging means it is not the problem with your code. Please check your text to speech engine "Speech Rate". You can find "Text to Speech" engine from settings application. Settings >> Language & Input >> Text to Speech Options. This path may be different in your device. Please verify it.